# iOS two tabbar button same naviguation controller with segue

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, segue

i have a Tab Bar Controller with two "buttons"

I want the two "buttons" show the SAME naviguation controller, but one button set the rootviewcontroller var to "a" and the second button set the var to "b"

Is it possible using storyboard and segue?

[image]

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the rootViewController from the storyboard. But you can do so programatically.

```
UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
```

//For tab 1

```
window.rootViewController = a;
```

//For tab 2

```
window.rootViewController = b;
```

Comment: Are you sure you have anderstand the question before to answer?

Comment: Seeing your answer now I understand and I must say you had asked your question in the most horrible way.

Comment: :) next time i will draw a sheme to be more explicit.. :)

Answer (score 0):

After an afternoon of google search, i haven't found a way to do this with segue.

But i found an answer that use the tag of the tabBarItem to differentiate the uiviewcontroller to initiate.

```
    if(self.navigationController.tabBarController.tabBar.selectedItem.tag == 1){
        self.typeToDisplay = "a"
    }else{
        self.typeToDisplay = "b"
    }
```